# A simple hide/show for faqs that saves to cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cookie

Why is this not saving the cookie when you refresh the page?

http://jsfiddle.net/jBVBL/

Or would it be better practice to save only 1 cookie with the value of every li with ".active"

```
var hideshow = $(".hideShow");

hideshow.children().not(".active").each(function(index, value){
    var tis = $(this);

    if($.cookie('hideShow_id'+index) == index){
        tis.addClass(".active");
    } else {
        $(this).find("div").hide();
    }            
});

hideshow.find('h3').click(function(e){
    var tis = $(this);
    var tisindex= tis.parents("li").index;
        $.cookie('hideShow_id' + tisindex, tisindex);

        tis.next().slideToggle('2000');
        tis.parent().toggleClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});


<ul class="hideShow">
        <li class="active">
         <h3><a href="javascript:;">Pellentesque nec leo cursus ipsum rhoncus volutpat nec eget mi.</a></h3>
         <div>
               <p>Nam velit metus, vulputate eget sodales ut, dignissim vehicula nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
             <ul>
                 <li>
                     <strong>Pellentesque</strong> nec leo cursus ipsum rhoncus volutpat nec eget mi.</li>
                 <li>

                     <strong>Nam</strong> quis lectus enim, ac euismod urna.</li>
                 <li>
                     <strong>Donec</strong> varius massa augue, at feugiat tortor.</li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <h3><a href="javascript:;">Pellentesque nec leo cursus ipsum rhoncus volutpat nec eget mi.</a></h3>
     <div>
           <p>Nam velit metus, vulputate eget sodales ut, dignissim vehicula nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <strong>Pellentesque</strong> nec leo cursus ipsum rhoncus volutpat nec eget mi.</li>
             <li>

                 <strong>Nam</strong> quis lectus enim, ac euismod urna.</li>
             <li>
                 <strong>Donec</strong> varius massa augue, at feugiat tortor.</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <h3><a href="javascript:;">Pellentesque nec leo cursus ipsum rhoncus volutpat nec eget mi.</a></h3>
     <div>
           <p>Nam velit metus, vulputate eget sodales ut, dignissim vehicula nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <strong>Pellentesque</strong> nec leo cursus ipsum rhoncus volutpat nec eget mi.</li>
             <li>

                 <strong>Nam</strong> quis lectus enim, ac euismod urna.</li>

         </ul>
     </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Using: https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a different cookie for each index, and they never match the one you look for on page load. In addition, you have different cookie name strings 'hideShow-id' vs 'hideShow_id'

Comment: Ok thanks, can you suggest how to fix this I have tried but have not worked

Comment: don't concatenate the index to cookie name, cookie name should be static

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($.cookie('hideShow-id') == index){
```

and

```
 $.cookie('hideShow_id' + tisindex, tisindex);
```

are clearly two completely different cookies

EDIT:

You are also horribly misusing `index`. First of all it is a function, not a property. But even then, you are going to get different indexes on load and click because you are confusing two different indexes

```
tis.parents("li").index()
```

is the index if the `li` tag among its siblings, where as

```
.each(function(index, value)
```

will give you index within the set you are iterating, which are clearly two different sets, because of the `.not(".active")` part.

Comment: I have updated the code to fix this, although this doesn't seem to have solved the issue

Comment: Updated the answer with more issues.